# Concurrent Dictionary AddOrUpdate method 3rd parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, System.Drawing.Color> _colorSet;      

public void BuildColorSet(IList<string> colorNames, string prefix, bool forceLastToGray)
{
    var size = forceLastToGray ? colorNames.Count - 1 : colorNames.Count;

    int nbHue = 6;
    int nbCycle = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)size / nbHue);

    var saturationMax = nbCycle <= 2 ? 1.0 : 1.0;
    var saturationMin = 0.3;
    var luminanceMax = nbCycle <= 2 ? 0.85 : 0.85;
    var luminanceMin = 0.3;
    var maxSaturationShift = 0.30;
    var maxLuminanceShift = 0.15;

    var interval = 1.0 / Math.Min(size, nbHue);

    var saturationShift = (saturationMax - saturationMin) / (nbCycle - 1);
    saturationShift = Math.Min(saturationShift, maxSaturationShift);
    var luminanceShift = (luminanceMax - luminanceMin) / (nbCycle - 1);
    luminanceShift = Math.Min(luminanceShift, maxLuminanceShift);

    var hueShift = 0.0;

    var saturation = saturationMax;
    var luminance = luminanceMax;
    for(var i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(i > 0 && (i % nbHue == 0)) // Next Cycle
        {
            saturation -= saturationShift;
            luminance -= luminanceShift;
            hueShift = hueShift == 0 ? interval/2 : 0;
        }
        var hue = interval*(i%nbHue) + hueShift;

        System.Drawing.Color color = HSL2RGB(hue, saturation, luminance);

    _colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color, ???);
    }
    if(forceLastToGray)
    {
        _colorSet.TryAdd(prefix + colorNames[colorNames.Count - 1], System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
    }

    _cssDirty = true;
}
```

I want to be able to update the dictionary if the color exists with new value. And also add to dictionary if the color is not there in dictionary.
I am using the AddOrUpdate but not able to get the 3rd parameter(form the lambda expression OR delegate method) of the AddOrUpdate method.
Any idea how my 3rd parameter would look like?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Did you check the documentation at all ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665.aspx

Comment: do you see the ??? in the AddOrUpdate. That is the parameter I am missing. Any ideas how I can form that parameter.

Comment: Yes - Read the documentation.

Comment: _colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color,(colorNames[i],_colorSet) =>
                {
                    _colorSet.TryAdd(prefix + colorNames[i], color);
                    return _colorSet;
                });

Comment: I tried that but it will not build. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: This is a nice blog article on ConcurrentDictionary that may be more readable than the api doc: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/08/9945809.aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx):

> updateValueFactory
>       Type: System.Func
>       The function used to generate a new value for an existing key based on the key's existing value

This will leave the value in the collection alone if it already exists:

```
_colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color,
            (key, existingVal) =>
            {
                return existingVal;
            });
```

This will replace the value in the collection with the same one specified for the insert:

```
_colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color,
            (key, existingVal) =>
            {
                return color;
            });
```

You can perform conditional logic, comparisons between the old value and new value, or update the original object in the function, for example.

```
_colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color,
            (key, existingVal) =>
            {
                if (existingVal.Name == "Red")
                    return existingVal;
                else
                    return color;
            });
```

Comment: The key in the ConcurrentDictionary is prefix + colorNames[i], and value = color is System.Drawing.Color.   Any idea what key, existingVal would be??

Comment: "key" would the the key of the existing item matching that key, so a value equal to prefix + colorNames[i].

existingValue will be the System.Drawing.Color object that already exists in the dictionary for the key: prefix + colorNames[i].

So in your case, key is a string and existingVal is a System.Drawing.Color. The datatypes are generic based upon how you declared the generic data types of the ConcurrentDictionary object variable.

Answer (score 1):

As per the web page asawyer gave you, what's required is a function

```
Func<TKey, TValue, TValue>
```

In this case it looks like you are passing a string and a Color but how you want to combing them is largely upto you. You need a function that returns a Color so the following should work from a syntax perspective.

```
(key, oldValue) => oldValue
```

I've no idea who you might calculating the new value. You could for example use your new color

```
_colorSet.AddOrUpdate(prefix + colorNames[i], color, (key, oldValue) => color);
```

Comment: The String is the KEY and the Color is the Value. Any idea what the expression will be -- I mean the (key, oldValue) => color

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't care if the color is already there; you always want to update the value in the dictionary. In that case you're better off using the normal indexer, e.g.

```
_colorSet[prefix + colorNames[i]] = color;
```